# knowing end of message in protocol with msgpack

Tags: c, protocols, msgpack

How do you manage end of a message in a protocol ? I use msgpack-c and the only solution I found is to send the header before the payload (separately).

Send the header to client :

```
// header
{
  "message_type": "hello",
  "payload_size": 10
}
```

The client received the header, unpack it, and allocate a buffer of "payload_size", receive data from stream, and if the buffer is complete the message is finish.

I want to send header and body succinctly

```
{
  "header": { "message_type":"hello", "payload_size": 10},
  "payload": {...} // can come in multiple frame
}
```

My problem is that I don't know if it's possible to partially unpack the header for knowing the size before receiving the full message (splitted if > 4096kb due to libevent restriction)

How would you do that ? I am open to all solutions.

Comment: I would send header packet with its packet size and a number that is the count of following payload packets incoming. Then each payload packet should contain its size and data (and its identification number optionally). Of course higher level implementation is required, to rearrange information when collected. Each packet must have its size, both header or payload.

Comment: You could extract the header and payload fields manually, then feed them through a JSON parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## C++

### Using unpack() function

You can use `offset` parameter of unpack() function.
See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_unpacker#client-controls-a-buffer

Here is a code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#incluee <msgpack.hpp>

int main() {
    msgpack::sbuffer buf;
    msgpack::pack(buf, std::make_tuple("first message", 123, 56.78));
    msgpack::pack(buf, std::make_tuple("second message", 42));
    std::size_t off = 0; // cursor of buf
    {
        // unpack() function starts parse from off (0)
        auto oh = msgpack::unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), off);
        // off is updated to 25. 25 is MessagePack formatted byte size
        // of ["first message",123,56.78] 
        // (I use JSON notation but actual format is MessagePack)
        std::cout << "off:" << off << std::endl;
        std::cout << *oh << std::endl;
    }
    {
        // unpack() function starts parse from off (25)
        auto oh = msgpack::unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), off);
        // off is updated to 42. 
        // 42 - 25 = 17. 17 is MessagePack formatted byte size
        // of ["second message",42] 
        // (I use JSON notation but actual format is MessagePack)
        std::cout << "off:" << off << std::endl;
        std::cout << *oh << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
off:25
["first message",123,56.78]
off:42
["second message",42]
```

msgpack-c unpack() manage the position of buffer internally.
You don't need to pass `payload_size`.

In addition you can mix non-msgpack format data in the buffer.

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| MessagePackBytes1  | Any format user knows size  | MessagePackBytes2  |
+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

Let's say user knows the data structure that contains MessgePackBytes1(unknown size), any format data (known size), and MessgePackBytes1(unknown size).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#incluee <msgpack.hpp>

int main() {
    msgpack::sbuffer buf;
    msgpack::pack(buf, std::make_tuple("first message", 123, 56.78));
    std::string non_mp = "non mp format data";
    buf.write(non_mp.data(), non_mp.size());
    msgpack::pack(buf, std::make_tuple("second message", 42));
    std::size_t off = 0; // cursor of buf
    {
        auto oh = msgpack::unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), off);
        std::cout << "off:" << off << std::endl;
        std::cout << *oh << std::endl;
    }
    {
        std::string extracted{buf.data() + off, non_mp.size()};
        std::cout << extracted << std::endl;
        off += non_mp.size();
    }
    {
        auto oh = msgpack::unpack(buf.data(), buf.size(), off);
        std::cout << "off:" << off << std::endl;
        std::cout << *oh << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
off:25
["first message",123,56.78]
non mp format data
off:60
["second message",42]
```

### Using unpacker

It is a little advanced but it might fit streaming usecases.
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_cpp_unpacker#msgpack-controls-a-buffer
Here is an example that unpacking MessagePack from continuous and scattered receiving message.
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/700167995927f0348fb08ae2579440c1bc135480/example/boost/asio_send_recv.cpp#L41-L64

## C

C version is basically similar to C++.

### Using unpack() function

C version has the similar unpack function.
Here is the prototype:

```c
msgpack_unpack_return
msgpack_unpack_next(msgpack_unpacked* result,
        const char* data, size_t len, size_t* off);
```

You can pass `off` as offset similar to C++ version. C doesn't have reference so you need to pass the address of `off` using `&off`.
See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_c_overview#using-unpack-function

If you want to know individual variable length field size such as stirng, you can access `size` member variable of unpacked object.
For example:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    struct msgpack_object* ptr;
} msgpack_object_array;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    const char* ptr;
} msgpack_object_str;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    const char* ptr;
} msgpack_object_bin;

typedef struct {
    int8_t type;
    uint32_t size;
    const char* ptr;
} msgpack_object_ext;
```

See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_c_overview#object

### Using unpacker

See https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v2_0_c_overview#using-unpacker

Comment: Thank you ! What's the equivalent of buf.write() in C ?

Comment: It is msgpack_sbuffer_write() . https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/c3df1bb26ebdd01d618ecca7ae2d6b4e37d5abd7/include/msgpack/sbuffer.h#L60